Invariance of the Lebesgue measure
It is well known that the Lebesgue measure is the unique (up to a multiplicative constant) sigma-finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ which is translation invariant.
I am wondering if a similar characterisation holds for manifolds when translations are replaced by volume-preserving compactly supported diffeomorphisms.
In particular, let $(M,g)$ be a smooth complete Riemannian manifold with finite volume measure $\text{vol}_g$.
Let $\text{Diff}_0(g)$ be the group of smooth diffeomorphisms of $M$ which are compactly supported (i.e. each of them coincides with the identity outside a compact set) and volume-preserving (i.e. each of them preserves $\text{vol}_g$ by push forward).
Question: is it true that (up to a multiplicative constant) $\text{vol}_g$ is the unique finite Borel measure on $M$ which is invariant for the push forward action of $\text{Diff}_0(g)$?
It is not difficult to see that any such measure has null atomic part and that any such measure which is also absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\text{vol}_g$ must coincide with it (up to a multiplicative constant). However, it is not clear to me if any such measure must have null singular continuous part w.r.t. $\text{vol}_g$. This, together with the above considerations, would imply the desired statement.
Any suggestion or reference would be very much appreciated!
On the notion of sigma-finite (resp. finite) Borel measure: As it was pointed out in one answer below, the notion of "sigma-finite Borel measure" is not completely standard and, depending on it, the statement in the first paragraph of this question may be or not be true. What I mean by "sigma-finite Borel measure" on a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is a function $\mu: \mathscr{B}(X, \tau) \to [0,+\infty]$ which is countably additive, satisfies $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and for which there exists a countable family of sets $(B_i)_i \subset \mathscr{B}(X, \tau)$ such that $\cup_i B_i = X$ and $\mu(B_i)<+ \infty$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Here $\mathscr{B}(X, \tau)$ denotes the Borel sigma-algebra generated by $(X, \tau)$. By "finite Borel measure" on a topological space $(X, \tau)$ I mean a sigma-finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $(X, \tau)$ which additionally satisfies $\mu(X)<+\infty$. $\mathbb{R}^d$ (resp. $(M,g)$) is always endowed with the topology induced by the Euclidean norm (resp. by the Riemannian distance $d_g$).

Just to avoid potential misunderstandings: perhaps in your second paragraph you could clarify that translations are being replaced by volume-preserving diffeomorphisms (otherwise the result is trivially false)

Also, you're not referring to volume that preserves diffeomorphisms, but to diffeomorphisms that preserve volume, hence volume-preserving diffeomorphisms rather than volume preserving diffeomorphisms. It's similar to the difference between a man eating shark and a man-eating shark: the former is a customer in a seafood restaurant and the latter scares people away from beaches. (Many people no longer use hyphens in the traditional way, but almost everybody still understands it.)

As you can probably tell, English is not my first language :) I fixed it.

Tangentially related is the uniqueness of the Haar measure on locally compact groups.

@MichaelHardy In your final sentence, to what does "it" refer? I do not have a copy of Fowler to hand.

@YemonChoi I meant almost everybody still understands things in which hyphens are used in the traditional way.

@YemonChoi Many publishers of books, magazines, and newspapers still use hyphens in the traditional way, but advertising and package labeling do not.

The result is true in the following formulation (which I believe implies yours): if $(M,\omega)$ is a manifold with a volume form¹ and $\mu$ is a locally finite Borel measure on $M$ such that $\phi_*\mu=\mu$ for every compactly supported diffeomorphism $\phi$ with $\phi^*\omega=\omega$, then $\mu$ is a multiple of the $\omega$-volume on every connected component of $M$.
Suppose that the result is true for the open unit Euclidean ball, which means that it must be true for all Euclidean balls by scaling. Then it must be true in the case of $M$. Indeed, write $x\sim y$ for the relation “there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ and $y$ such that $\mu_{|U}=\alpha_U(\operatorname{vol}_g)_{|U}$”. This is clearly symmetric. Note that if $\mu$ and $\operatorname{vol}_g$ are proportional on two open sets $U$ and $V$, then they are proportional on $U\cup V$ provided these open sets intersect. This shows that the relation is transitive. If we have shown that it is reflexive, then $M$ is decomposed into equivalence classes. On those classes, the argument above shows that the measures are indeed proportional. But these must be open, so every connected component must be contained in at most one class, and the measures are proportional on every connected component, which is what we wanted. Now it suffices to show that every point is contained in a neighborhood where the measures are proportional, which by the Euclidean version reduces to showing that every point admits a neighborhood that is volume-diffeomorphic to some small Euclidean ball. But this is a well-known fact, it is often quoted as “a volume form has no local structure”; it can be proven via Moser's trick, or via an explicit construction.
So let us work with some finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb B^d$, invariant under $\operatorname{Diff}_0(\mathbb B^d)$. Now suppose that for every pair of cubes $C=\prod_{i=1}^d[a_i,a_i+\delta)$ and $C'=\prod_{i=1}^d[a'_i,a'_i+\delta)$ whose closure is included in the open unit ball, one can find a volume-preserving diffeomorphism $\phi$ with compact support sending one to the other. Then such pairs must have the same (finite) volume for $\mu$, and by a monotone class argument again we conclude that $\mu=\alpha\lambda_d$, where $\alpha=\mu([0,\varepsilon)^d)/\lambda_d([0,\varepsilon)^d)$ for some (hence all) small $\varepsilon>0$.
The result on cubes is a consequence of the following lemma.

Lemma.
Let $(M,\omega)$ be a smooth (boundaryless) manifold with a smooth volume form. Let $X:M\to TM$ be a divergence-free vector field, and $K\subset M$ a compact subset.
If $M$ is contractible,² then there exists a divergence-free vector field $Y:M\to TM$ with compact support that coincides with $X$ over a neighborhood of $K$.

This concludes since we can take for $X$ the constant field $a'-a$, and $K$ the closed convex hull of $C$ and $C'$. Then the flow of $Y$ at time 1 is the expected diffeomorphism.
Proof of the lemma. For $(M,\omega)$ fixed, let $\delta$ be the unique linear differential operator $\mathcal C^\infty(\Lambda^{d-2})\to\mathcal C^\infty(TM)$ (and in fact the unique map) such that $\iota_{\delta\alpha}\omega=\mathrm d\alpha$ for every $(d-2)$-form $\alpha$ (the interior product
$$(v\mapsto(\iota_v\omega)_x):T_xM\to\Lambda^{d-1}T_x^*M$$
must be a bijection for every $x$ because $\omega$ is a volume form; one can write an expression in local coordinates and check that it gives a smooth differential operator). Any vector field of the form $\delta\alpha$ has zero divergence, since
$$ (\operatorname{div}_\omega(\delta\alpha))\omega
 = \mathcal L_{\delta\alpha}\omega
 = (\mathrm d\iota_{\delta\alpha}+\iota_{\delta\alpha}\mathrm d)\omega
 = \mathrm d^2\alpha + \iota_{\delta\alpha}\mathrm d\omega = 0+0 = 0. $$
In the reverse direction, if $M$ is contractible, then every vector field $X$ with zero divergence must be of the form $\delta\alpha$. Indeed, by the same reasoning as above, we see that $\iota_X\omega$ must be closed, hence it is exact equal to some $\mathrm d\alpha$. By uniqueness, $X=\delta\alpha$.
Now let $X$ and $K$ be as in the lemma. Let $\alpha$ be a $(d-2)$-form such that $X=\delta\alpha$, and $f:M\to\mathbb R$ be constant equal to 1 on a neighborhood of $K$, with compact support in $M$. Then $Y=\delta(f\alpha)$ satisfies all the expected conditions.

¹ The proof is local, hence will work equally well with a density on a non-orientable manifold.
² In fact we can see clearly in the proof that we only need $H^{d-1}(M,\mathbb R)=0$. I don't know if the lemma still holds when we do not have this condition, but I would actually guess that it does not in general, since we need to have the volume “flow around $K$” to compensate for the fact that we constrict the flow outside the support of the diffeomorphism.

Thank you very much for your answer! Could you please elaborate a bit how you pass from the case of an arbitrary Euclidean open ball to the one of a (smooth connected complete) Riemannian manifold? The remaining part of the argument is clear!

The hypothesis $H^{d-1}(M,\mathbb R)=0$ is not superfluous, as can be seen from the case $M=\mathbb R\times N$ with $N$ a closed manifold, $X=\partial_t$ and $K={0}\times N$: any volume-preserving flow that coincides with translations in a neighborhood of ${0}\times N$ must push the volume to infinity, hence cannot have compact support (and $H^{d-1}(M,\mathbb R)=H^{d-1}(N,\mathbb R)=H^0(N,\mathbb R)\neq0$).

No, the Lebesgue measure is not a unique (up to a multiplicative constant) invariant sigma-finite Borel measure on $n$-space.  See

Elekes, Márton; Keleti, Tamás.
Is Lebesgue measure the only σ-finite invariant Borel measure?
J. Math. Anal. Appl. 321 (2006), no. 1, 445–451.

The Lebesgue measure and integral, foundationally speaking, are trickier than many people believe.  For example, in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, it is possible to have a strictly positive function with zero Lebesgue integral; see

Kanovei, Vladimir; Katz, Mikhail.
A positive function with vanishing Lebesgue integral in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory.
Real Anal. Exchange 42 (2017), no. 2, 385–390.


The point of that paper is to discuss uniqueness for different notions of "sigma-finite Borel measure". According to the notion that I thought to be standard (but apparently is not) the paper shows in Theorem 0.1 that the unique sigma-finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ which is translation-invariant is indeed (up to a multiplicative finite non-negative constant) the Lebesgue measure (considered as a measure defined on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$. I will point out this subtlety in the question.
